# Why does filtering on a non-existing (non-selected) column work?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The following minimal example

```
val df1 = spark.createDataFrame(Seq((0, "a"), (1, "b"))).toDF("foo", "bar")
val df2 = df1.select($"foo")
val df3 = df2.filter($"bar" === lit("a"))

df1.printSchema
df1.show

df2.printSchema
df2.show

df3.printSchema
df3.show
```

Runs with non errors:

```
root
 |-- foo: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- bar: string (nullable = true)

+---+---+
|foo|bar|
+---+---+
|  0|  a|
|  1|  b|
+---+---+

root
 |-- foo: integer (nullable = false)

+---+
|foo|
+---+
|  0|
|  1|
+---+

root
 |-- foo: integer (nullable = false)

+---+
|foo|
+---+
|  0|
+---+
```

However, I expected something like

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`bar`' given input columns: [foo];
```

for the same reason, I get

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`asdasd`' given input columns: [foo];
```

when I do

```
val df4 = df2.filter($"asdasd" === lit("a"))
```

But it does not happen. Why?

Comment: probably spark create something like SQL request witch is lazy combination of select and filter: `select foo from X where bar = 'a'`. There X is table with both `bar` and `foo` columns. Sorry for my English

Comment: most of requests Spark make lazy and with optimization

Comment: Lazy optimization should not affect the results, i.e., change the semantics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm leaning towards calling it a bug.  An `explain plan` tells a little more:

```
val df1 = Seq((0, "a"), (1, "b")).toDF("foo", "bar")

df1.select("foo").where($"bar" === "a").explain(true)
// == Parsed Logical Plan ==
// 'Filter ('bar = a)
// +- Project [foo#4]
//    +- Project [_1#0 AS foo#4, _2#1 AS bar#5]
//       +- LocalRelation [_1#0, _2#1]
// 
// == Analyzed Logical Plan ==
// foo: int
// Project [foo#4]
// +- Filter (bar#5 = a)
//    +- Project [foo#4, bar#5]
//       +- Project [_1#0 AS foo#4, _2#1 AS bar#5]
//          +- LocalRelation [_1#0, _2#1]
// 
// == Optimized Logical Plan ==
// LocalRelation [foo#4]
// 
// == Physical Plan ==
// LocalTableScan [foo#4]
```

Apparently, both the `parsed logical plan` and `analyzed (or resolved) logical plan` still consist of `bar` in their `Project nodes` (i.e. [`projections`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(relational_algebra))) and the filtering operations continue to honor the supposedly removed column.

On a related note, the logical plans for the following query also consist of the dropped column, thus exhibiting similar anomaly:

```
df1.drop("bar").where($"bar" === "a")
```

Comment: Thanks. I just opened a Jira issue for that: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-30421