# Filtering on dropped column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I created a pyspark dataframe `df1` by dropping a column age from an existing dataframe `df` having `id`, `name`, `age` fields. when I apply a filter on `df1` using column `age`, I am getting an output instead of an error. What is the reason pyspark did not throw any errors?

Comment: see spark predicate pushdown. spark pushes the filters to the top level if possible.

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59597678/why-does-filtering-on-a-non-existing-non-selected-column-work

It is a bug with spark and this is the issue on their Jira: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-30421